# how to implement mousemove after mousedown using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouseevent, mousemove, mousedown

I need to implement a `mouse over` after `mouse down` , so that when user pressed and move the cells will be opened (minesweeper)

Here's my code !

```
case 2:
    {
        if ($(this).hasClass("open") || $(this).hasClass("bomb") || $(this).hasClass("close")) {
            var X_axis;
            var Y_axis;
            $('.close').mousemove(function (event2) {
                if ($(this).attr('row') != X_axis && $(this).attr('column') != Y_axis) {
                    var obj = $("[row='" + X_axis + "'][column='" + Y_axis + "']");
                    $(obj).addClass("close");
                }
                $(this).removeClass("close");
                X_axis = $(this).attr('row');
                Y_axis = $(this).attr('column');
            });
        }
    }
    break;


case 2 --> mean left mouse click
```

Comment: Do you have a specific problem with the above code?

Comment: yes , when user press on a cell and moves to another cell ,

Comment: the previous cell must be closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oh sorry , here's the solution

```
 if ($(this).attr('row') != X_axis || $(this).attr('column') != Y_axis)
```

use || not && , because the array 2d and maybe current cell x_axis equal to previous cell  x_axis ....